# AngularJSで定数?っぽいオブジェクトを定義したい

Tags: javascript, angularjs

以下のような、ステータスとその順番等を管理するオブジェクトを定義したいのですが、
この場合、AngularJSではどこにどのように定義するべきなのでしょうか？
サービスとして定義するべきなのでしょうか？

```
status = [
           { waiting  :{index:1, icon_img:'xxx1.png'} },
           { operating:{index:2, icon_img:'xxx2.png'}},
           { complate :{index:3, icon_img:'xxx3.png'}}
         ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular1.*系であれば、`module.constant`でconfigフェイズでも使用できるDIが定義できます。

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/59naga/mcj0bq1h/)

```
angular.element(document)
.ready(function(){
  angular.bootstrap(document,['myApp']);
});

angular.module('myApp',[])
.constant('ORDER_BY',['foo','bar','baz'])
.config(function(ORDER_BY){
  console.log(ORDER_BY);// ['foo','bar','baz']
})
;
```

> 参考：
>   [constant, value, service, factory, providerの使い分け - AngularJS - angular.jsメモ - Qiita](http://qiita.com/akkun_choi/items/618d2d9107029ab0422e#constant-value-service-factory-provider%E3%81%AE%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%84%E5%88%86%E3%81%91)